# Problem in accessing elements of matrix through nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

TypeError is coming in my program and I am not able to understand What is wrong with code

```
n=int(input())
matrix=[]

for i in range(n):
    row=input().split(" ")
    row=[int(row[i]) for i in range(n)]
    matrix.append(row)

sume=0

for i in range(n):
    sume+=matrix[i][i]

j=-1
for i in range(n):
    sume+=matrix[i][j]
    j-=1
    if j<-n:
        break

j=((n+1)/2)-1

for i in range(n):
    sume+=matrix[i][j]

sume += sum(matrix[j])
print(sume)
```

Error is

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "source_file.py", line 18, in

```
sume+=matrix[i][j]
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Comment: Please fix indentation. It is impossible to see what is code is doing

Comment: Also, the problem is in this line: `j=((n+1)/2)-1`. Its result is float, because if `n` is even, `j` can be something like 2.5.

Comment: I have corrected indentation problem.